# how to interpret a question with a 'where' in the sentence

Tags: australian-english, where

I am a bit confused on how to intepret a question like the following which has a *where* in it.  The question is

> List all towns where Tom stayed 8 weeks or more outside his home town.

I'm not sure if the "8 weeks" applies to the period he spent out of his home town cumulativeley or each individual town.  For example, lets say Tom spent the following periods out of his home town cumulatively

- Town A: 3 weeks
- Town B: 3 weeks
- Town C: 3 weeks

Looking at the above data, Tom spent 9 weeks out of his home town cumulatively but in each town (A,B,C) he spent only 3 weeks (less than 8 weeks).  So when answering the original question, should the answer be

- Town A, Town B, and Town C since he spent 9 weeks (more than 8 weeks) in total out of his home town OR
- None, since he has not spent more than 8 weeks in each town.

Comment: The title is confusing. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with "where", and is just about how to interpret "stayed 8 weeks or more" in context. You'd have the same issue with another relative pronoun such as: "List all houses in which Tom stayed 8 weeks or more aside from his own house" etc.

Answer (score 1):

##### The Interpretation Should Definitely Be  *Individual*, Not *Cumulative*

If the question were mean to be read as cumulative, then the question would mean something like "list all the towns which contributed to Tom having stayed away for eight weeks" – which logically would include every town, so that interpretation of the question would not make sense, and would logically amount to "list all the towns where Tom stayed" – all of them logically being 'out of his hometown' and so all of them logically contributing him being away.